# Q: How to configure ClickHouse to return NULL instead of 0?

Tags: clickhouse

Let's say I have a table created as such without any record:

```
    create table metric (date Int32) Engine=MergeTree ORDER BY (date);
```

If I run this query

```
    select max(date) from metric;
```

ClickHouse returns

```
+-----------+
| max(date) |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

instead of

```
+-----------+
| max(date) |
+-----------+
|      NULL |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Is possible to configure ClickHouse to return NULL without have to write query like this:

```
select max(toNullable(date)) from metric;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setting [aggregate_functions_null_for_empty](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#aggregate_functions_null_for_empty):

```sql
SELECT max(date)
FROM metric
SETTINGS aggregate_functions_null_for_empty = 1

/*
┌─maxOrNull(date)─┐
│            ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└─────────────────┘
*/
```

or consider using [OrNull](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/combinators/#agg-functions-combinator-ornull)-combinator:

```sql
SELECT maxOrNull(date)
FROM metric

/*
┌─maxOrNull(date)─┐
│            ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└─────────────────┘
*/
```